# How to get back original value(real number) from floats value without including exponential notation in c#?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I just converted 16 digit number as a **float** value.

```
 float myVal =(float) 4447962230071312;
Console.WriteLine(myVal);
```

This gives the output:
4.44796223007131E+15

I tried below code,

```
long originalVal = (long)myVal;
Console.WriteLine(originalVal);
```

This gives the output:
4447962352582656

```
Console.WriteLine(myVal.ToString("0.#########"));
```

This gives the output:
4447962000000000

since, How to get back original value of **4447962230071312**

Comment: `float` (`Single`) uses `23` bits for fraction part. Thus integers beyond `2**24 - 1 == 16777215` will be rounded up and round up errors will be inevitable

Comment: is there any coding stuff to get rid of this issue? Nothing!

Comment: you can try changing to `double` with `52` bits long fractional part (up to `9007199254740991` which happens to be more than `4447962230071312`)

Comment: You can use `decimal` type

Comment: Why convert it to a `float` at all?  Just leave it as a `long`.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: in case of explicit rounding (e.g. `int result = Math.Round(123.45);`) you are quite right: round to the nearest with ties to even; in case of *rounding up errors* it's not specified (as far as I know), Java language even provides `strictfp` modifier to ensure that rounding will be performed in the same way on different platforms.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: If value doesn't fit fractional part, it will be rounded (usually if we have a periodic fraction like `3.0 / 7.0`). However, some FPU (e.g. Intel one) has 80-bit `long double` which can be implicitly used in computations:
`1000000000000000001d - 1000000000000000000d == (long double) 100000000000000001 - (long double) 1000000000000000000 == 1` 
the usage of such types (hidden digits) and rounding algorithms I far as I know are not specified.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: I'm sorry for the mess, it seems I've misused `up` (which I thought could have been added to `round` to make *phrasal verb* like `close up`, `read up`, etc.). I didn't noticed that `up` means *direction* as well, and thus brings mess (I've edited the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` (or `Single`) uses `23` bits for fractional part only, and thus `Single` can represent integer values *without round error* up to

```
2**(23 + 1) - 1 == 16777215
```

you can switch to `double` which has `52` bit fractional part and so can represent integer value up to

```
2**(52 + 1) - 1 == 9007199254740991 > 4447962230071312
```

For details, see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

**Code:**

```
  double myVal = 4447962230071312.0;

  long originalVal = (long)myVal;
```

Comment: your explanation is fine. but, I had [similar](https://superuser.com/questions/413226/why-does-excel-treat-long-numeric-strings-as-scientific-notation-even-after-chan) issue. that's why I tested with that real number.